# Finding a recursive formula for a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the sequence $(a_n)= 1 + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ and need to find a recursive formula.
I compared the differences between the first five terms and found that the difference in every step increases by $\frac{1}{2}$, for example: $a_4$ = $\frac{9}{8}$ , $a_3$ = $\frac{5}{4}$ , $a_2$ = $\frac{3}{2}$; $a_4$ - $a_3$ = $-\frac{1}{8}$ , $a_3$ - $a_2$ = -$\frac{1}{4}$.

But now I'm stuck.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

From the fact that $a_n=1+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ we have that $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{2^{n}}$. Now notice that
$$\frac{a_n}{2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}=a_{n+1}-\frac{1}{2}.$$
Therefore we get the following recurrence relation 
$$a_{n+1}=a_n/2+1/2$$

Comment: could you please explain the second line
$\frac{a_n}{2} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2^{n}} = a_{n+1} - \frac{1}{2}.$
 I don't understand how you derived it from the given facts
Thank you!

Comment: $\frac{a_n}{2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^n}$ is just a division by 2. Now since we know that $a_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{2^n}$, then $a_{n+1}-\frac{1}{2}=1+\frac{1}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^n}$. And the last on is exactly the expression we found for $a_n/2$. So $a_{n+1}-\frac{1}{2}=a_{n}/2$

Answer (score 2):

Evaluating a few of the differences by hand is a good idea, but in the end you have to do it symbolically rather than just numerically:

$$\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}-a_n&=\left(1+\frac1{2^n}\right)-\left(1+\frac1{2^{n-1}}\right)\\
&=\frac1{2^n}-\frac1{2^{n-1}}\\
&=\frac1{2^n}-\frac2{2^n}\\
&=-\frac1{2^n}\;,
\end{align*}$$

so

$$a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac1{2^n}\;.$$

That’s probably the most straightforward approach. Alternatively, you might notice that since $a_n-1=\frac1{2^{n-1}}$ and $a_{n+1}-1=\frac1{2^n}=\frac12\cdot\frac2{2^{n-1}}$, we always have

$$a_{n+1}-1=\frac12(a_n-1)=\frac12a_n-\frac12\;,$$

and hence

$$a_{n+1}=\frac12a_n+\frac12\;.$$

Comment: Thank you! I guess the second part of your answer is (somewhat) similar to mrprottolo's, but the formula seems to work backwards, it gives me $a_{n-1}$ instead of $a_{n+1}$.

Comment: @Pilotf4: It's actually exactly like **mrprottolo**'s, except that I made a still algebra error that effectively turned the subscripts around, as you noticed. Fixed now, though. You're welcome, and thanks for catching the mistake!